npm ERR! node-gyp rebuild fails with 401 error when fetching Node.js headers from Artifactory
When running the 'npm install' command, dependencies are downloading fine from Artifactory using same npmrc file. However it fails when trying to fetch headers from Artifactory w/ a 401 error. Even though the registry is the same that's already being authenticated too. Any suggestions? Do I need to add more?

npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.0.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.15.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp http GET <URL>
npm ERR! gyp http 401 <URL>
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: 401 response downloading <URL>
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19045


I added a dist-url to point at the correct Artifactory repo & also tried downloading the headers locally, but it can only fetch them via https.
